# How to build fast exponentation for modular?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I need to find modular value of some big number which I cannot calculate by calculator (i.e $233^{351} \pmod {853}$. How can I build a fast exponentiation table for this?

Comment: See my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296073/computing-large-powers/296407#296407 Regards

Comment: Check for efficient exponentiation algorithms, like the binomial ones. Or just use GNU's `bc()`, or a computer algebra package (probably http://www.wolframalpha.com can do it for you). For programs, look for multiprecision packages like gmp.

Comment: Azmoti/mixedmath's solution is a good one for a general case.  It can also be done recursively, which would be useful if you wanted to do it as part of a computer program.  It is technically possible to do it in fewer multiplications.  I can do it in 12, but there may be a solution in 11 I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the method of "Repeated Squaring."

That is, you compute 
$$550 \equiv 233^2 \mod 853$$
$$538 \equiv 550^2 \equiv 233^4 \mod 853$$
$$277 \equiv 538^2 \equiv 233^8 \mod 853$$
$$812 \equiv 277^2 \equiv 233^{16} \mod 853$$
$$ \ldots $$

In this way, you increase the powers of $233$ very quickly, and each step is computationally very easy. At the end, you end up multiplying the appropriate numbers together. For example, to compute $233^{30} \mod 853$, you would multiply
 $$233^{16} \cdot 233^8 \cdot 233^4 \cdot 233^2 \equiv 812 \cdot 277 \cdot 538 \cdot 500 \mod 853$$

You might notice that for this, we are using the binary expansion of the exponent. In binary, $30 = (11110)_2$, which is why we used the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th repeated squares to get $233^{30}$.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I kinda get a concept of repeated squaring, now I need to apply it and do it myself

Comment: What if an exponent is like 233? Its binary is 11011111 then I need to use 1th to 5th and 7,8th? if a binary is like 10000001 do I still need to calculate intermediate value to get next step?

Comment: @REALFREE: Yes, that's exactly right. You still need the calculations, and you take only the binary parts you need.